# What ways are there to run Matlab scripts from an R-Shiny app?

Tags: r, matlab, shiny

I am trying to create an app in R-Shiny which displays results from calculations done in Matlab. My goal is to be able to enter some settings in Shiny and run Matlab based on those. The Matlab script then performs some data collection and transformation tasks, saves the results in a .csv file, which can be read into R and be displayed in Shiny. So basically, Matlab updates a dataset which is then displayed in Shiny.

I have both a working Shiny-app to plot and summarise the data in tables and the Matlab-code to update the dataset. However, I can't find a way to connect both processes directly, so I run them separately one after the other.

Using a .bat-file, I did manage to execute the Matlab-code from R. My issues with this are that I can't change any elements in the Matlab-code and that R doesn't detect when Matlab has finished generating the output-file. Especially the second issue is annoying since R does not know when it can start to generate all plots and tables for Shiny.

Is there a more direct solution?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: If you can access the command line from R-Shiny, you can run the matlab function using `matlab -r myfunc(arg1,arg2)` (see https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102082-how-do-i-call-matlab-from-the-dos-prompt for more options). When it returns you will know it has finished.

Comment: Can't you use the [R.matlab package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! @Papooch: Does this mean that when I call a matlab function in R with something like system("matlab -r myfunc(arg1,arg2)"), R will not execute the next line of code until the system command has finished?

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent: I didn't get the package to work, can you maybe give an example on how to do it?

Comment: @TheHerold I assume so, but you should try yourself. Also you might want to add some additional startup parameters (see the link) to hide the matlab window and also an exit statement at the end of the matlab code. EDIT: you need to supply a `-wait` parameter if you want to wait for the completion.